# JS select value of multidimentional objects

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

So, I have following js setup:

```
var NAMES = []; 
function INFO(id,first,middle,last){ 
  var newMap = {};
  newMap[id] = [first, middle, last];
  return newMap ;   
}
```

Then,

Then I get following result:

[image]

I am trying to select the individual value like below:

For example, I want to select "Sean" under "185"

```
var f = '185';
select_data = NAMES[f][0];
```

But I keep getting an error saying that "0" is not an identifier.

I am bit confused. Can someone help me out how to select the value properly?

Comment: `select_data = NAMES[0][f][0]; `

Comment: sigh,, that was a silly oversight.. thank you for pointing out.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the object inside the array first, so it should be as follows

```
var f = '185';
select_data = NAMES[0][f][0]; 
//           -------^----- getting first element from array, which is the object
```